# Hide rows based on cells contaning all zeroes or no values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset where every row is a General Ledger (GL) account and in each column there is the value for the relevant period.

[image: Print screen of Data Set]

I would like to hide all GL accounts (rows) where no values (or zero values) are included for all periods (columns).

The code below seems to work for the "No values".

How do I hide all the rows with only zeroes (or all rows with zeroes or "no values"?

If one period has an amount, the row shouldn't be hidden.

```
Sub hide()

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A1:F6")

If c.Value = "" Then
   c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
   c.EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Furthermore once any amounts change in a row this code should also make the unhidden rows reappear. At this moment it hides a row that has no value, but once this changes, the hidden row doesn't reappear anymore.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA hide column if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548910/vba-hide-column-if)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See code below if you want to test for both all blanks or all zeros and hide row if either present. Starts with an unhide of all rows.

```
 Sub hide()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet5")
    Set targetRange = ws.Range("A1:F6")

    targetRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For Each c In targetRange.Rows
       If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(c,"<>0") - WorksheetFunction.CountIf(c,"") = 0) And (WorksheetFunction.CountA(c) - WorksheetFunction.Count(c) = 0) Then
           c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot QHarr, I tried your code and it almost works, however once there is a combination in GL of "No value" and a "zero" the formula doesn't hide that GL row. Do you have any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: you mean a row with only blanks and zeros?

Comment: I have amended the test conditions in my answer. Please let me know if works.

Comment: The new line of code doesn't work as good as the previous one :)
Now more lines than just the zero's and blanks disappear. 

My prior question was indeed about a GL line item with only blanks and one zero. That should also be hidden, however it remains visible

Comment: What was the condition the original was failing on ? The new code will hide a row if it is all zeros, all blanks, or a mixture of blanks and zeros. It will hide rows if they have either text in and/or number >0. Can you update post with image of data particularly showing row where failing?

Comment: when I try it out it just hides all the rows that I submit in the range. So not only the ones that fulfill the requirements.

So if I set the range at A1:F6, it hides row 1 till 6 no matter which amounts I have in these rows

Comment: Can you post an image of the data please? Also, have you checked that the blank cells are indeed empty with an isempty() test against each cell in the range?

Comment: Failing that just add to the original two conditions the following line as an additional OR test   WorksheetFunction.CountA(c) - WorksheetFunction.Count(c) = 0

Comment: I've added a print screen to the top of my original post. This data set hides all rows 1-6

Comment: Thank you very very much QHarr! It works like a charm! :) This really helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to check every row completely before deciding if to hide it or not. Currently, the last cell of every row decided if a row is hidden.

Give the following code a try. It sets a range to all cells of a row and uses the function `CountA` to count number of cells that are not empty.

```
Sub hide()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, row As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        For row = 1 To 6
            Dim myRange As Range
            Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(row, 1), .Cells(row, 6))
            .Rows(row).EntireRow.Hidden = (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange) = 0)
        Next row
    End With
End Sub
```